# HTML - What is the correct way to do the following layout?

Tags: html

Diagram A can be accomplished by having a valign="top" and align="right" on the parent TD. The red rectangle is a div with style="float:right". This works on most browsers, but not IE. IE will put a linebreak before the div. The Text is not surrounded in any tag. It is the first thing in the TD.

The problem with the setup in Diagram A was solved by containing the text inside a Div with style="float:right" and placing that div AFTER the original red div, causing the layout in Diagram B. This appears to work in all browsers, but I have doubts that I'm accomplishing this layout requirement in the correct way.

[image]

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

I can't use a table, because the div on the right side has a slightly variable width and the distance between the green text and the left side of the right-side Div is very important. Basically, the absolute position of the text on the left depends on what happens in the right side div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching doctypes to get better control of your layout?

Specifically moving to one of the strict doctypes ([A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/))

**UPDATE**
Adding [Daniels link to Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types) comparison of doc types.

Comment: This is the Doc Type I'm using. Is this good or bad? <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

Comment: From W3Schools: "The doctype declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in.

The doctype declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers can render the content correctly."

Comment: @hamlin11: I would never use a transitional doctype unless there was a very good reason. Switch to strict and see what happens.  You'll find that the rendering will be a lot more consistent across browsers.

Comment: @hamlin11: Your doctype, HTML 4.01 trans without a system identifier, will trigger quirks mode, which should be avoided at all costs. If you need a transitional doctype for whatever reason and can't use a strict one, at least add a system identifier. It should look like this: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: Forgot to add this nice link. Wikipedia lists a lot of possible doctypes and which mode they trigger in different browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types

Answer (score 1):

So, your solution is to float both the text and the DIV to the right. This seems OK.

Another way to go would be to set display:inline-block on the DIV. Try that.

**Live demo:** http://www.vidasp.net/tinydemos/div-inside-td.html